# Examples of primitive permutation group with a base of size 2

Tags: group-theory

Good evening,
I was looking for examples of a primitive permutation group with a base of size 2. In particular, i was searching for a primitive group with base 2 with a particular propriety: having a lot of bases of sizes 2. I mean, a group such that exists an $a$ and $a_1,...,a_n$ such that $(a,a_1),...,(a,a_n)$ are all bases for $G$.
Thanks,
And good Evening.

Comment: It's the afternoon where I am.

Comment: I have answered this question, but it does not really meet the standards of this forum, because it is lacking context. You should tell us why you are interested in solving this problem (is it a homework or exam question for example), and whether you have had any ideas about it yourself.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. I understood it and i found it very useful. I am sorry if my question didnt meet the standards of the forum, i didnt know if the context could help so i didnt insert it, but next time i will add. Anyway, i am doing a research thesis on bases of primitive groups. I think i have found an interesting  theorem, but in order to make it works i need a primitive group like above. I reality, i needed a group with a stronger property, i dont know if you will be able to answer me. In any cases, i will editing my question, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For a prime $p$, let $G$ be the normalizer in $S_p$ of the subgroup $P = \langle (1,2,3,\ldots,p) \rangle$ of order $p$. Then $G$ has order $p(p-1)$ and is 2-transitive (in fact it is *sharply* 2-transitive), and hence primitive. Then  $(a,b)$ is a base for $G$ for any distinct $a,b \in \{1,2,3,\ldots,p\}$.

Comment: As i said, thanks for the reply. I have found also some groups coming from the  projective linear group. In reality, i was searching a more specific group: a group with the property above but that has the elements $a_1,...,a_n$ in different orbits respect of the action of the stabilizer of $a$. I searched a lot in literature but i couldnt find it, cause if the group is 2-transitive then i dont have the property and i found only primitve group with a base of size 2 that were 2-transitivity. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For the dihedral group of order $2p$ with $p$ an odd prime we have that property. The stabilizer of a point $a$ has $(p-1)/2$ orbits of length $2$, so you can choose one $a_i$ from each of these orbits, and each $(a,a_i)$ is a base.

Comment: Thanks so much, i understood your answer, the example was easier than i thought!  Anyway, thanks! I hope this question will be useful also to someone else in the future.